# wxPython event starts up at startup

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

So I am a complete beginner at python and usually code in C/C++ or Java. In the process of developing a GUI my events keep getting called at the start of the program running instead of when I click the button. (i know my indents are wrong because I needed to put it into a code block). How do I make my events only get called when I left click the button?

```
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(QuadDash, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(1024, 780))            
    self.SetBackgroundColour("white")      
    pnl = wx.Panel(self)
    cbtn = wx.Button(pnl, label='Start Quad', pos=(20,30))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.start_quad_event(), cbtn)        
    self.Show(True) 

def start_quad_event(self):
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Test", "ABC", wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
    dlg.ShowModal()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    qd = QuadDash(None, title='QuadCopter Dashboard')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Try ``qd = QuadDash(None, title='QuadCopter Dashboard')`` instead of just ``QuadDash(...)``. I'm not sure if the object you create actually sticks around, or if its reference count goes to zero and it is garbage collected.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger the dialog is still showing up at start up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.start_quad_event(), cbtn)
```

You actually call `start_quad_event()` and pass the result to `bind()`.

The correct line is:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.start_quad_event, cbtn)
```

Note: No parentheses. Here you actually pass the function to `bind()`.

Comment: so it does not show up on start up. Also i changed `wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN` to `wx.EVT_BUTTON` and I get this error when clicking the button `TypeError: start_quad_event() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
`

Comment: Ok I fixed it I needed to change my `start_quad_event(self)` to `start_quad_event(self, event)`

Comment: Use ``def start_quad_event(self, evt):``.

wx passes an event object with additional information to your callback.